# Reactjs: why use const {} = this.props and why put it inside the render function

Tags: reactjs

I am learning reactjs and I see many people write, for example

```
class Trees extends Component {

    render() {
        const { plantTrees } = this.props;
        return( ...
```

I want to know why use `const {} = this.props`? Is there any benefit to using it? what is the purpose of initializing the const variable inside the render function?

Comment: Const isn't a variable, it's a keyword. That's *destructuring*, it's equivalent to `const plantTrees = this.props.plantTrees;`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In reality this is not only for React, but it's an ES6 feature for JavaScript called destructuring assignment, it's a better way to retrieve values from an object or an array. In your example, without ES6 we must use

```
const plantTrees = this.props.plantTrees;
```

but with ES6 we simply use

```
const { plantTrees } = this.props
```

In the case of an array, we can use this

```
const [,price] = ['car',10000]
```

to retrieve the second element on the array and store it on a constant called price.

More information here: https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment

Comment: thanks for your **great editing** @jonrsharpe , sorry new at stackoverflow

Comment: No worries, I'd suggest you read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to get to grips with the syntax.

Comment: This answered whats going on with the destructuring, but not why with a render() method in React one might want to wrap this.props as const versions of themselves?

Comment: In the codebase I work with, it seems to be done for concision. So you if you need `this.props.foo` several times in a function, all those references can simply be `foo`.